How to customize Date Format in Angular?
I have an Angular App, where i display a lot of dates to the user.
I use Angular Material in my App and transloco for translations.
I use english and german language. The english dates are displayed exactly like i want, but for the german dates i want to change the format, because they are displayed without leading zero.
i.e. 5.4.2024 ist displayed, but i want 05.04.2024.
How can i customize the displayed date format for one of the languages (german)?
In the component html i have always something like this:
<mat-form-field class="w-full">
        <mat-label>Eintrittsdatum</mat-label>
        <input
            [class.input-changed]="entryDateHasChanged()"
            matInput
            readonly
            [matDatepicker]="entryDatePicker"
            [(ngModel)]="entryDate"
            (ngModelChange)="entryDateChange()"
            name="entryDate" />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle
            matSuffix
            (click)="clearEntryDate($event)">
            <mat-icon
                matDatepickerToggleIcon
                svgIcon="mat_outline:clear"></mat-icon>
        </mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle
            matIconSuffix
            [for]="entryDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #entryDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

In my app.config.ts i have in the provider section this:
provideNativeDateAdapter(),

and in my app.component.ts i have a subscription to the language change like this:
constructor(
        private translocoService: TranslocoService,
        private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>,
    ) {}

    async ngOnInit() {
        this.dateAdapter.setLocale(this.translocoService.getActiveLang());
        this.translocoService.langChanges$.subscribe(lang => {
            if (lang==='en') {
                this.dateAdapter.setLocale('en-GB');
            } else {
                this.dateAdapter.setLocale('de-DE');
            }
        });
    }

I think i have to provide a custom DateAdapter Class. But i don`t know how to do that.

First, you add the moment.js library to your project.
https://momentjs.com/

import moment from 'moment'
import 'moment/locale/es'  
moment.locale('es')

then on the language change, you can change the date format with the method moment.locals('es') to moment.locals('de').
You should follow the documentation of moment.
